# get m3u file from url stream iptv

Tags: video-streaming, m3u8, m3u, iptv

Someone knows if it is possible to get the all m3u file from the informations of one channel stream which is like this :

http://server.net:40:40/play/live.php?mac=00:1B:44:11:3A:B7&stream=2802&extension=ts&play_token=XXXXXXXX&sn2=

normally to get a m3U
[http://server.net:9999/get.php?username=${IPTVUSER}&password=${IPTVPASS}&type=m3u_plus&output=ts](http://server.net:9999/get.php?username=$%7BIPTVUSER%7D&password=$%7BIPTVPASS%7D&type=m3u_plus&output=ts)

is there a username and a password in my link?

i can change the number of the stream (2802) manually , and it works, i get other channels ...